# How can I replace an instance on an object with that of its corresponding numerical index value using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can place an instance of an object at each index but how can I replace each instance with it's **corresponding numerical index value**?

[image: img1]

**My goal is to show the numerical index value and where it's located at/on an object (for faces/edges/vertices) using geometry nodes.**

**Example:**
Instead of showing cylinders have it display the corresponding index value.

[image: img2]

My thought process was to:

1. Convert each numerical index to a string and
2. Place that string at it's corresponding index location.  But ran into an issue at the start with converting the index value to a string.

Note: The goal is to do this in Geometry Nodes.  Is this even possible without using a loop (which GN doesn't have yet)?

I'm using GN 3.1

Comment: i think it is not possible because [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aikdu.png both won't take fields, but just constants. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

although i think it is not possible with geometry nodes (ok it is, if you make all the text-meshes by hand) ...BUT...you can do it very easy with animation nodes and geometry nodes.

Idea: let animation nodes make the collection of texts. Let GN use it and show it.

GN setup:

[image]

AN setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks...I guess it's one more thing to hope for...
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/loops-in-geometry-nodes-proposal/21357  

At least the person who wrote Animation nodes proposed loops in geometry nodes..  (Jacques Lucke)

Comment: loops are necessary. I really hope it will come

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want to "steal" an accepted answer here in any way, I just want to give a proof:
>
> **Yes, the task can be solved wonderfully with Geometry Nodes!**

Just in a nutshell, here is the node tree as an overview:

[image]

[image]

*...please excuse this short post, I will go into more detail soon when I have more time.*

[image]

Comment: Hehe.. I made one of these too.. I got interested in Ginymbi's [Attribute Viewer](https://ginyumbi.gumroad.com/l/jbrmi) .. (did you introduce me to it?).. and stripped it back into what seemed to me to be more resuable modules :)

Answer (score 1):

Was told about a great tool call index-viewer for blender which helps with this.  Yes it's free.

https://artofriaz3d.gumroad.com/l/indexviewerfields

[image: img1]

The node groups is wild!!!!!

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at first I thought hey cool there's a value to string node,that should work. But nah. ;)
My solution is to have one instance on point node for the single digits, one for the tens and one for the hundreds.
And a some math nodes to fix the positions of the digits.

I uploaded some of my tests to twitter:
https://twitter.com/DaBo_de/status/1507702609993416712?s=20&t=z7y5o8JqgCGg86JQEye8og

Comment: Can't really see the image/animation/node network (to fuzzy/small).  Maybe if you posted the node network here we can see how it looks / works.