# Individual Mesh Face Index Values to String (String to Curves) Nodes 3.3.1

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking for a way to label each face of a mesh with the face index (integer ID).

I have come up with the following but so far can't seem to figure out how to get individual values on each string to curves instance.

Any ideas?

[image: Blender 3.3.1]

Comment: The issue is quite complicated, since you can't get there by simply instantiating an object. Either you build it yourself with nodes (the hard way), or you use one of the addons described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255989/

Comment: Here you can find an explanation why your approach does not work: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/